# ADFS - How to be specific on a groups claim

Tags: adfs

How do you specify a particular set of groups to look for and return in the ADFS authentication rather than searching for and returning all a user's groups in the response message?

This is a question in response to an answer given by Jim B for this question: [Getting Nested User groups in ADFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/713201/getting-nested-user-groups-in-adfs/713235#713235?newreg=24aa4a36efa946bcae79769a5d45582f)

Jim said, " You should be specific in the group you are looking for rather than returning all groups, aside from security and performance issues on the server, a large number of groups returned could cause your app to crawl. – Jim B Aug 11 '15 at 18:25 "

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be a good idea to first read up on how claim rules work. I've found the following technet articles quite helpful:

[AD FS 2.0 Claims Rule Language Primer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/ad-fs-2-0-claims-rule-language-primer)

[Understanding Claim Rule Language in AD FS 2.0 & Higher](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4792.understanding-claim-rule-language-in-ad-fs-2-0-higher.aspx)

The short version is that you end up stringing together various claim rules that "store" query data and then tweak/filter the data before you actually "issue" the claim with the resulting groups.

Here's an example that we use in our environment. For this particular relying party, we wanted to return all group memberships beginning with "myapp." including nested groups.

- Rule 1: Fetch the user's DN

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://contoso.com/UserDN"), query = ";distinguishedName;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

- Rule 2: Fetch all nested group CNs using member attribute

```
c1:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 && c2:[Type == "http://contoso.com/UserDN"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group"), query = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={1});cn;{0}", param = c1.Value, param = c2.Value);
```

- Rule 3: Filter the resulting groups using Regex

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value =~ "(?i)^myapp\."]
 => issue(claim = c);
```